# Foreach loop and variables with locking

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Basically what I want to do is this psuedo code

```
List<DatabaseRecord> records;

List<ChangedItem> changedItems;

Parallel.ForEach<DatabaseRecord>(records, (item, loopState) =>
{
    if (item.HasChanged)
    {
        lock (changedItems)
        {
            changedItems.Add(new ChangedItem(item));
        }
    }
});
```

But what I'm worried about is locking on the changedItems. While it works, I have heard that it has to serialize the locked object over and over. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why not lock on an `Object` and have any other code that works on changeItems also lock on that `Object`?

Comment: Regular threaded apps, sure. But not TPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use a ConcurrentCollection for your changedItems. Something like ConcurrentQueue? Then you wouldn't need to lock at all.

**Update:**

With regard to the ConcurrentQueue, the Enqueue won't block the thread in keeping the operation thread safe. It stays in user mode with a SpinWait...

```
public void Enqueue(T item)
{
    SpinWait wait = new SpinWait();
    while (!this.m_tail.TryAppend(item, ref this.m_tail))
    {
        wait.SpinOnce();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the ConcurrentQueue is lock-free under the hood. I also think the TPL is implemented with those concurrent collections. Will check w reflector tomorrow.

Comment: I need to stop commenting on SO at 1:38 in the morning. My comments are starting to become incoherent.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you use PLinq instead? No locking needed:

```
changedItems = records.AsParallel()
                      .Where(x => x.HasChanged)
                      .Select(x => new ChangedItem(x))
                      .ToList();
```

Since you are projecting into a new list of `ChangedItem` and do not have any side effects this would be the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: +1 - This is the way to go - as long as the `ChangedItem` constructor is thread safe, and not reliant on shared state (which the previous lock could have easily "fixed" by avoiding any issues)

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't since I'm doing more code on the object than just checking the .hasChanged...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that locking on the list will cause the list to serialize/deserialize as locking takes place on a private field available on all objects (syncBlockIndex). However, the [recommended way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to go about locking is to create a private field that you will specifically use for locking:

```
object _lock = new object();
```

This is because you have control over what you lock on. If you publish access to your list via a property, then code outside of your control might take a lock on that object and thus introduce a deadlock situation.

With regards to PLinq, I think deciding to use it depends on what your host and load is like.  For example, in ASP.NET, [PLINQ is more processor hungry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/02/08/9960003.aspx) which will get it done more quickly but at the expense of taking processing away from serving other web requests. The syntax is admittedly a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you using this code in single thread ? 
if it's single thread , No lock needed . 
Does it works alright when you remove the line " lock (changedItems) "
The code that @BrokenGlass have posted is more clear and easy to understand.